# django response method POST don't render to the html template

Tags: html, django, post, request

I have two  request function in views one is with .get method and the other one with .post. Both of the function works properly because in the the terminal the code is 200.

[01/Apr/2021 08:04:39] "GET /search/search HTTP/1.1" 200 4164
[01/Apr/2021 08:04:57] "POST /search/search HTTP/1.1" 200 4164

The problem comes when i try to render the function with .post method to the html template nothing appear on the html page.

```
def wind_search(request):
if request.method == 'post':
        city = request.post['city']
        weather_city_url = urllib.request.urlopen('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&appid=1a7c2a40a0734d1dc18141fc6b6241bb').read()
        list_of_data = json.loads(waether_city_url)


        # main wind information
        wind_speed = list_of_data['wind']['speed']
            # wind_gust = wea['current']['wind_gust']
        wind_deg = list_of_data['wind']['deg']
        # wind conversiont m/s to knots
        def wind_converter(w):
            knots = 2
            kt = (float(w)) * knots
            return kt

        wind_response = wind_converter(wind_speed)
        #convert wind degree in cardinal direction.
        def degrees_to_cardinal(d):

            dirs = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']
            ix = round(d / (360. / len(dirs)))
            return dirs[ix % len(dirs)]

        direction = degrees_to_cardinal(wind_deg)

        wind_data = {

        "wind_response":wind_response,
        "wind_direction":direction,
        }

else:
    wind_data={}

    context = {"wind_data":wind_data}
return render(request, 'API/wind_search.html',context)
```

This is the html template:

```
    {% extends "API/base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<!--Jumbotron -->
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4">Wind search</h1>
    <p class="lead">Write the city and check th wind condition. </p>
<!-- form input search tool -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <form method="post" class="col-md"">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class=" input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Choose Your City ...">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
      </div>

      </form>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    {% if wind_response and wind_direction %}
        <h4><span>Wind Speed :</span> {{wind_data.wind_speed}}</h4>
        <h4><span>Wind_Direction :</span> {{wind_data.wind_direction}}</h4>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I think the problem is with the html because basically the view don't show any error message, so i tried to change couple of time the html code but without success. Any help/ explenation is nice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have not rendered the response for POST. there is only one render in your program

Comment: Can you please more specific I don't understand. I mean the render at the end of the function don't work also for the POST method?

Comment: The line `context = {"wind_data":wind_data}` should not be indented. As it is now, it's part of the `else:` block.

Comment: Also check your `wind response` and `wind direction` references in the template to be sure they match the `context` data.

Comment: I remove the indentation and check the references but still the same, any other advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the render and redirect template,

```
def wind_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #this block of code manages if there is a POST request...
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        weather_city_url = urllib.request.urlopen('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&appid=1a7c2a40a0734d1dc18141fc6b6241bb').read()
        list_of_data = json.loads(waether_city_url)
        
        # main wind information
        wind_speed = list_of_data['wind']['speed']
        # wind_gust = wea['current']['wind_gust']   
        wind_deg = list_of_data['wind']['deg']
        # wind conversiont m/s to knots
        
        def wind_converter(w):
            knots = 2
            kt = (float(w)) * knots
            return kt

        wind_response = wind_converter(wind_speed)
        #convert wind degree in cardinal direction.
        def degrees_to_cardinal(d):

            dirs = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']
            ix = round(d / (360. / len(dirs)))
            return dirs[ix % len(dirs)]

        direction = degrees_to_cardinal(wind_deg)

        wind_data = {

        "wind_response":wind_response,
        "wind_direction":direction,
        }
        # the page that you want to load after submitting your POST request <-----------------------------------------------------
        return redirect( 'redirect to a view ' )
    



    #the below block of code will cater for the GET method request
    else:
        wind_data={
            'foo' : 'foo'
        }

        #the page you want to render on a Get Request <-----------------------------------------------------
        return render(request,'render the required html for GET request' , wind_data)
```